# PHP foreach() loop

Tags: php

```
$string = "The complete archive of The New York Times can now be searched from NYTimes.com " //the actual input is unknown, it would be read from textarea  

$size = the longest word length from the string
```

I assigned and initialized array in for loop, for example array1, array2 ....arrayN, here is how i did

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) {
    ${"array" . $i} = array();
}
```

so the $string would be divided in the length of the word

```
$array1 = [""];
$array2 = ["of", "be", ...]
$array3 = ["the", "can", "now", ...] and so on
```

So, my question is how to assign in simple for loop or foreach loop $string value to $array1, $array2, $array3 ....., since the input text or the size of the longest word is unknown

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your asking - but you don't seem to understand how arrays work. Since you want an array where each element is text, simply do: $array[0] = "";, $array[1] = "of, be ..."; and so on (in your example, you have defined many arrays, but just used them as strings!)

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably start with `$words = explode(' ', $string)`
then sort the string by word length

```
usort($words, function($word1, $word2) {
    if (strlen($word1) == strlen($word2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strlen($word1) < strlen($word2)) ? -1 : 1;
});

$longestWordSize = strlen(last($words));
```

Loop over the words and place in their respective buckets.
Rather than separate variables for each length array, you should consider something like

```
$sortedWords = array(
    1 => array('a', 'I'),
    2 => array('to', 'be', 'or', 'is'),
    3 => array('not', 'the'),
);
```

by looping over the words you don't need to know the maximum word length.

The final solution is as simple as

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $wordLength = strlen($word);
    $sortedWords[ $wordLength ][] = $word;
}
```

Comment: Final solution looks oddly familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($words as $w) {
    array_push(${"array" . strlen($w)}, $w);
}
```

This splits up `$string` into an array of `$words` and then evaluates each word for length and pushes that word to the appropriate array.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use explode().

$string = "The complete archive of The New York Times can now be searched           from NYTimes.com " ;

$arr=explode(" ",$string);
$count=count($arr);

$big=0;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     $p=strlen($arr[$i]);
if($big<$p){ $big_val=$arr[$i]; $big=$p;}

     }
echo $big_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the word length as the index and append `[]` each word:

```
foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $word) {
    $array[strlen($word)][] = $word;
}
```

To remove duplicates `$array = array_map('array_unique', $array);`.

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => The
            [2] => New
            [3] => can
            [4] => now
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => complete
            [1] => searched
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => archive
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => of
            [1] => be
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => York
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Times
        )
)
```

If you want to re-index the main array use `array_values()` and to re-index the subarrays use `array_map()` with `array_values()`.

Comment: getting Undefined variable: array1 when i try to print $array1, $array2....and so on

Comment: That's not how arrays work.  Try something like: `foreach($array as $len => $list) { echo "$len : " . implode(', ', $list) . "<br>\n"; }`

Comment: If you want words of length 3 then `echo implode(', ', $array[3]);`